# How to set up java runtime environment in online server

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Actually I have to run my java war file having service  which i want to access .normally in pc we run eclipse and use tomcat to do so. But in server if I have space then how to run my war file over there.

Comment: So, you're asking how to deploy a war into Tomcat? Why don't you read the tomcat documentation? https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/deployer-howto.html

Comment: Normally in eclipse we run this file using tomcat but in online server there is no eclipse no tomcat at that time what is procedure

Comment: Install Tomcat?

Comment: You can't install the app onto a server if you haven't installed a server...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you just install tomcat on your server and deploy the war file to it. There is lots of documentation on how to do this.

I would turn to the tomcat documentation on how to get started:
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/introduction.html